# Installing internet Explorer 10 on windows 11

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-11

I deal with some website that requires login using Internet Explorer 10. How can I install IE 10 on windows 11? Yes, it needs to be IE 10 only, not a version after that.

Edit:

From the answers, it seems that we can not install IE 10 on windows 11. But, there might be an addon for some browser like chrome or Firefox which emulates IE 10 functionality. Any advice on this also would solve the problem.

Comment: See if this works>>>>>https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd

Answer (score 3):

> Installing internet Explorer 10 on windows 11

No. Windows 11 does not have IE available like Windows 10 had IE11 (not IE 10). IE will soon be completely uninstalled and unavailable on all systems.

Microsoft Chromium Edge has excellent Internet Explorer compatibility capabilities and I suggest you use Edge for your requirements.

Any attempt to run IE 11 (not IE 10) will launch Edge instead.

That is about all you can do at this point.

Comment: Just to be clear, IE10 couldn’t be ran on Windows 10, so there is no loss of functionality from that point of view. IE10 hasn’t been supported for more than 2 years. It has never been supported (nor will it ever be supported) on Windows 10. In less than 45 days IE11 will be removed from all supported versions of Windows

Comment: Thanks I meant to say that Windows 10 had IE 11 and I changed my post accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I install IE 10 on windows 11? Yes, it needs to be IE 10 only, not a version after that.

While it’s technically possible to run the offline IE11 installer on Windows 11, it’s impossible to run the application, because any attempt to run IE11 will actually just launch Microsoft Edge.

Additionally, it’s impossible to install IE10 on Windows 8+, since all versions between Windows 8 and Windows 11 (non-inclusive) only support IE11.

To achieve your goals, you will have to run a virtual machine running a version of Windows, that supports IE10.  **Realistically there is no other solution to your desired goals.**

Comment: Then, are there any free versions of virtual machines, and Windows 7 out there?